# Geometric Brownian motion without drift

Tags: randomness, brownian-motion

Let's say we have geometric Brownian motion:
$$
dS_t = \mu S_tdt + \sigma S_tdW_t
$$
Then the SDE becomes:
$$
S_t = S_0\exp\left(\left(\mu - \frac{\sigma^2}{2}\right)t + \sigma W_t\right)
$$
Say $\mu$ is zero and the drift is zero.  But below, the drift term $(\mu - \sigma^2)t$ becomes $(-(\sigma^2)/2)t$, which will make a drift occur. What gives?  Wouldn't it make more sense to drop the drift component entirely?

Comment: More sense in terms of modelling some specific real-life phenomenon? Or is the question about why the solution to $dS_t = \sigma\,S_t\,dW_t$ is not $S_t = S_0\, \exp (\sigma\,W_t)$?

Comment: The latter.  Just looking at the formula that is derived, it implies a drift over time.  If your drift is zero to begin with, why would there be a residual drift in the derived formula?

Answer (score 2):

Your logic is flawed, as a driftless SDE would still have **quadratic variation** applied to it. The quadratic variation would add a term $\sigma$, while $1/2$ comes from `ito Lemma`.

A martingale under a probability measure doesn't mean the solution wouldn't have a "drift" term.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be a bit more careful about the fact this is geometric, not additive, Brownian motion.

Were it additive the solution would be a family of normally distributed RVs as a function of time.

But GBM solves to give a log-normal distribution.  And the problem, in a nutshell, is that the expected value of a log-normal distribution is not simply $\mu$; it's median turns out to be $\mu$.  See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution