# Solution Geometric Brownian Brownian motion with no drift

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

This question has been asked before in here [Geometric Brownian motion without drift](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/175077/geometric-brownian-motion-without-drift/315548)
but I can't find what I want in the answers so ask again differently:
for $\mu=0$
$$
dX_t =\mu X_t dt + \sigma X_t dW_t = \sigma X_t dW_t
$$
Does it become:
$$
(1) x_T = e^{\sigma(W_T-W_t)}
$$
or
$$
(2) x_T = e^{0.5\sigma^2(T-t)+\sigma(W_T-W_t)}
$$
(2) seems unlikely for me because the process is clearly a local Martingale but (2) is not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general solution is
$$X_t=X_0 e^{(\mu-\frac{\sigma^2}{2})t+\sigma W_t} $$

If $\mu=0$, it is just 
$$X_t=X_0 e^{(\frac{\sigma^2}{2})t+\sigma W_t} $$

Comment: How will you relate this to the Martingale theory? Shoudn't X be a martingale

Comment: I think that's buried in the general solution.  Are you saying the closed-form general solution works for any $\mu$ other than zero?